# Como se puede dejar dos editText paralelos dentro de un ScrollView

Tags: android, edittext

Como se puede dejar dos editText paralelos dentro de un ScrollView
en esta imagen salen los editText uno debajo del otro, yo quisiera que salgan uno alado del otro puesto que los numero a ingresar no son mas de 4 digitos
[image: en esta imagen salen los editText uno debajo del otro]

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me fue de mucha utilidad, si pudiese puntuar tendrían mi voto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define la propiedad `android:orientation="horizontal"` al contenedor de ambos `EditText`, de esta forma se mostrarían ambos horizonalmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a los `EditText`, para que ambos elementos tengan el mismo tamaño puedes agregar la propiedad:

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

Ejemplo:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:hint="Texto Izquierdo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:hint="Texto derecho"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me fue de mucha utilidad, si pudiese puntuar tendrían mi voto

Comment: @EstebanAndrés Hola Esteban puedes puntuar en el lado izquierdo de la respuesta, revisa el [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Algo importante a señalar es que cuando usas `ScrollView` debes tener solo un elemento contenedor (elemento hijo) el cuál va ser recorrido por el `ScrollView`.
Para lograr lo que necesitas basta con agregar a tu código XML lo siguiente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="1234"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="1234"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--RESTO DE ELEMENTOS A AGREGAR-->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Con el valor `android:orientation="horizontal"` en el `LinearLayout` contenedor hará que tus `EditText` se distribuyan de manera horizontal.

Los valores `android:layout_weight="1"` en cada `EditText` son para lograr que tus elementos ocupen cada uno el 50% del espacio total en pantalla.

El resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya no es necesario android:weightSum="2"

Comment: @Jorgesys estas en lo correcto acerca de android:weightSum="2", más sin en cambio inputType lo agregue debido a que en la en la pregunta se dice que se va agregar un numero el cuál no va ser mayor a cuatro dígitos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me fue de mucha utilidad, si pudiese puntuar tendrían mi voto.

Gracias Gracias